# Server wan't send mail when using Google Mail service

Tags: email, vps, gmail

Situation:

Email MX service is on example.com BUT using google mail service.
A domain (web service) are on different IP address than google mail service on VPS host and on the same domain name example.com.

host example.com

```
   example.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   <--- VPS server, WEB service
   example.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
   example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
```

host -t mx example.com

```
example.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
example.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
```

On a same domain `example.com` we are using MX service google mail service.

PROBLEM: On a VPS server `example.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` a VPS server can't send an email to another `something@example.com` as a same domain.

WHAT I WANT? Using mail service MX from googlemail and VPS from another IP address.

And dig -t example.com

> ; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> example.com ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got
>   answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8318 ;;
>   flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512 ;; QUESTION
>   SECTION: ;example.com.            IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: example.com.       7200    IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> ;; Query time: 208 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) ;; WHEN:
>   Sun Jul  7 13:25:21 2013 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52

**Sending mail from google service can send to ALL.
Send mail from VPS server can send to ALL EXCEPT on the `example.com`**

Hint: CentOS using Plesk service with full VPS SSH access. What is best solution for working mail service on both and that can VPS send mail service on a same domain?

Comment: What do the mail logs on the VPS server say?

Comment: Nothing in `/var/log/maillog` -rw-------  1 root         root                0 Srp  7 00:42 maillog
-rw-------  1 root         root                0 Srp  1 00:42 maillog.1
-rw-------  1 root         root                0 Lip 23 00:41 maillog.2
-rw-------  1 root         root                0 Lip 17 00:40 maillog.3
-rw-------  1 root         root                0 Lip  9 00:40 maillog.4

Comment: Now I added into example.com nto VPS MX record. Waiting for propagation.

Comment: Why is downvoted me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using SMTP to connect another host and [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).